# Alternative to using callback function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I'm trying to have the second function be called after the scrolling animation of the first one finishes. I've seen that callback functions are used in similar situations however they seem to be more cumbersome and difficult to read. Is there an simpler or more clean way to achieve the same result?

```
$('#nav_experience').click(function scrollToExperience(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#Experience').offset().top
    }, 500);
})

function navbarExperienceActive(){
    scrollToExperience(function(){
        $('#nav_profile').removeClass('active');
        $('#nav_education').removeClass('active');
        $('#nav_contact').removeClass('active');
        $('#nav_experience').addClass('active');
    });
}
```

Also I appreciate the second function is quite repetitive and there may be a more elegant way to write it, I'm relatively new to JavaScript.

Comment: The code in the question won't work, for a couple of reasons. `scrollToExperience` isn't defined in `navbarExperienceActive`, and if it were the one that exists only as a `click` callback, it never calls the callback that `navbarExperienceActive` passes it. (Function *expressions* don't add the function to the scope where they appear, just function *declarations*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One modern approach to situations where we used to use callbacks is to use *promises*, which are particularly effective when combined with `async` functions and `await`. (Conceptually, "promises" go by many names — promises, futures, deferreds....)

Promises themselves still use callbacks, but by providing a standardized form of passing around promises for future callbacks, they markedly improve code that used to pass callbacks around just as arguments.

Your `scrollToExperience` might look like this, for instance:

```
function scrollToExperience(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('#Experience').offset().top
        }, 500, resolve);
    });
}
```

`navbarExperienceActive` might use it like this:

```
function navbarExperienceActive(){
    scrollToExperience().then(function(){
        $('#nav_profile').removeClass('active');
        $('#nav_education').removeClass('active');
        $('#nav_contact').removeClass('active');
        $('#nav_experience').addClass('active');
    });
}
```

On the face of it, that hasn't changed much; you still have to pass a callback. But if `navbarExperienceActive` had to combine this with other asynchronous actions, chain off it in other ways, etc., using promises makes that simpler and more standard between codebases.

But if `navbarExperienceActive` were an `async` function, it could use `await`:

```
async function navbarExperienceActive(){
    await scrollToExperience();
    $('#nav_profile').removeClass('active');
    $('#nav_education').removeClass('active');
    $('#nav_contact').removeClass('active');
    $('#nav_experience').addClass('active');
}
```

It still uses promises, but the code is written according to its simple logical flow rather than worrying about the fact that it has to wait for `scrollToExperience` to finish.

An `async` function always returns a promise; when you use `await` in the `async` function, if the value you pass it is a promise *(hand-waves details about "thenables")*, it returns its promise then settles that promise based on what happens to the promise you're `await`ing (and/or the logic following it).

---

I should note that the promise returned by `scrollToExperience` above is a bit unusual, because it always fulfills the promise, it never rejects it. The code using its promise relies on that fact that it never rejects its promise.

In general, though, it's important to be sure to either handle promise rejection or pass the *promise chain* on to something else that will. That's another place where `async` functions make life simpler: They automatically propagate promise rejections, exactly the way synchronous functions automatically propagate exceptions.

Comment: *(FWIW, I go into promises in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 8 of my new book, and `async`/`await` in Chapter 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.)*

Comment: Thanks for the in depth description of promises, this is exactly the type of alternate method I was hoping for and I'll be sure to have a look at your book. I changed my scrollToExperience() function to return a promise and changed navbarExperienceActive() to an async function however it appears navbarExperienceaActive() isn't being called when the click event is triggered

Comment: @Biggles-2 - Do you have anything set up to call it? In the question, the click event only calls `scrollToExperience`, not `navbarExperienceaActive`.

Comment: I thought I had but it hasn't worked, I must have made a stupid mistake or synthax error. How would you call both in the click event?

Comment: I've simply added the same click event for ```navbarExperienceActive```, the error in the console is ```Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: scrollToExperience is not defined``` from the line ```await scrollToExperience();```. I understand what this means but I'm not sure how to rectify it

Comment: @Biggles-2 - Define `scrollToExperience` outside of where you assign it as a `click` handler. As I mentioned in a comment on the question, the way it's defined there, it's not in scope.

Comment: That makes sense, I didn't see your previous comment. I've defined it outside of the click event and that has solved the problem. Unfortunately I now have the problem of ```scrollToExperience``` being called as soon as the webpage is opened. I'll try and figure out why. If you think of anything do let me know.